# Finding angle between two vectors .

Tags: vectors

I was studying vectors when i read a line stating that

" Angle bewtween two vectors is obtained by their dot product ( not from cross product ) ie. $ \theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac {A\cdot B}  {AB}) $ $\;$.
It is not always $ \sin^{-1}{ \frac {| A×B |}{AB} } $"

I cant seem to understand the line. can somebody pleaese explain it to me.

Comment: The cross product is only defined in $\mathbb R^3$; the dot product is defined in $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The angle between any 2 vectors has the range $[0,\pi]$.

Now, the principal range of $\cos^{-1}$  is $[0,\pi]$, while the range of $\sin^{-1}$  is from $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

So, $\sin^{-1}$ cannot describe angles from $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ properly, while $\cos^{-1}$ can.

For example, if $A×B = 0$, then $\sin^{-1} (0)$ can take the values $0$ and $\pi$. Thus, you are not able to know whether $A$ and $B$ are parallel or anti-parallel just from the cross product.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $\sin{\theta}=\sin(\pi-\theta)$ so that $\arcsin$ can't distinguish between these possibilities.  If the angle between the vectors in $105^\circ$, the $\arcsin$ function will report that the angle is $75^\circ$, since it takes values between ${-\pi\over2}$ and ${\pi\over2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is a property of the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I.e. we always have that

$$ \vec{A}.\vec{B} = (a_1, a_2) . (b_1, b_2) = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|.\cos(\theta)$$

from which the required formula quickly follows. You could derive this using the Pythagorean theorem.

A similar property holds for the cross product, although the given expression $\frac{|A \times B|}{AB}$ only takes values between $0$ and $1$, from which it should be obvious that it cannot always be correct (in particular when the angle is such that $\sin(\theta) < 0$).

Comment: It would work perfectly fine for $\sin\theta\lt 0$, but it cannot distinguish values from $[0,\pi/2]$ interval from $[\pi/2,\pi]$ interval.

Comment: This is equivalent to what I said. The $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ interval is where $\sin(\theta) \leq 0$.  In that interval, the formula gives wrong answers - off by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$. The sine function is continuous, has no other roots in that interval, so $\sin(x)>0$ for $x\in(\pi/2,\pi)$. If you want plot the function, or use a calculator for $\sin(3\pi/4)$